# Devexpress Double conditional FormatString

Tags: grid, format, devexpress, conditional-statements

I'd like to conditionally change the FormatString property of a grid's column.

The input is a double.

What I want to do is the following :

```
if (cellValue % 1 == 0)
    aColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "N0";
else
    aColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "N2";
```

Is there a way to do it at runtime without having to check each value of the column ?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use approach witn handling the [ColumnView.CustomColumnDisplayText](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomColumnDisplayTexttopic) event demonstrated by @kenrogers.

Or you can use [Custom Formatting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2142) feature for this column:

```
aColumn.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.Custom;
aColumn.DisplayFormat.Format = new CustomDoubleFormatter();

public class CustomDoubleFormatter : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter {
    public object GetFormat(Type format) {
        return this;
    }
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider provider) {
        bool hasFractionalPart = ((double)arg % 1.0 > double.Epsilon);
        return string.Format(hasFractionalPart ? "{0:N2}" : "{0:N0}", arg);
    }
}
```

P.S. For more detail about formatting cell values refer to [Formatting Cell Values](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1473) help article.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks. I prefer this approach instead of checking values at "display time". It's definitely quicker and stabler. 
Thanks again Dimitry !

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, no, there isn't.

Actually, what you have written would change the FormatString for the entire column, rather than a single cell, which is not what you want.

What I think you should do instead is handle the GridView's `CustomColumnDisplayText` event. Your handler would look something like:

```
void gridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "YourFieldName")
    {
        float value = Convert.ToDouble(e.Value);
        if (value % 1 == 0)
            e.DisplayText = string.Format("{0:N0}", value);
        else
            e.DisplayText = string.Format("{0:N2}", value);
    }
{
```

Note that if you defined your own columns for the GridView, you could change the first conditional expression in the event handler to `if (e.Column == myColumn)`, which should be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kenrogers. But I prefer the approach proposed by Dimitry which seems to be quicker at run time.

Thanks !